# Load all files from folder in theme – Security concerns?

Tags: themes, security

I'm using this code below in a config file to automatically require other PHP files in the same directory and in subdirectories. This helps my work flow become more efficient. I'm concerned that I should be using more wordPress security features in this code as I'm currently using none.
Can someone recommend some wp security enhancements for this code if there are any?

```
<?php 
$theme_path = 'wp-content/themes/' . get_template() . '/acf';
$theme_path_admin = '../wp-content/themes/' . get_template() . '/acf/';
if (!is_admin()) {

  $filepath= new SplFileInfo($theme_path);
} else {
  //filepath from admin

$filepath= new SplFileInfo($theme_path_admin);
}
req_php_files($filepath->getRealPath()); ?>
```

Comment: This is a pretty broad question... what specifically are you worried about? Where is this file used?

Comment: its used in a wordpress theme, im worried about not following best practice security enhancements

Comment: im looking for some sort of sanitation of the files before they get included so thats its not malicious.

Comment: Where are the files coming from? Do you control them?

Comment: Yes i control the files that are being imported

Comment: Then you don't need to be concerned about sanitising them, right?

Comment: How does `req_php_files()` look like? You should at least check the type of files you are including. Maybe consider a white list or some additional checks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Only so much security can be added at the php layer. To gain even more security, modify the .htaccess file, disabling directory browsing, disabling XML-RPC, and deny access to WP-specific files.

```
    <files .htaccess>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </files>
    <files readme.html>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </files>
    <files readme.txt>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </files>
    <files install.php>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </files>
    <files wp-config.php>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </files>

    # Rules to disable XML-RPC
    <files xmlrpc.php>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </files>

    # Rules to disable directory browsing
    Options -Indexes
```

*Don't want ../pxs/wp-content/uploads/ open to the web, after all. What if you uploaded a contract with significant details or something?*

---

Banning the HackRepair.com Blacklist in your .htaccess file is a good idea too. Here's what the beginning of that'd look like:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Acunetix [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^binlar [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bolt\ 0 [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot\@yahoo\.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BOT\ for\ JCE [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^casper [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^checkprivacy [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [NC,OR]
```

Comment: this is not even the beginning of hardening wordpress security

Comment: You're right - the OP already took the beginning steps. The advice I offer includes some next steps for the OP to take. 

To disable directory browsing, for instance, is probably useful to the OP since the OP's website is currently allowing for directory browsing. Ya, the OP is asking to improve their PHP code, and my advice isn't about PHP -- but recommending the OP think outside the PHP layer. Given the broad nature of the question, I believe this is good advice. 

That said, yea, you're totally right, there're a lot of security things the OP should do and know about beyond just this.